# How to allocate amount of rows according to amount of rows in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, reference, excel-2021

How do I insert amount of rows according to data from another sheet?

[image: This is my reference data from sheet a]

I have 5 data out of the 10 rows I have (I keep the empty rows for spare)

[image: This is my expected output in sheet b]

How do I make it so the data here corresponds to the amount of data in reference sheet? Such that if I have 5 names, this sheet will automatically return 5 rows where the data will be in. If I have 6 names in the reference table, this sheet will have 6 rows for the data, etc.

I'm thinking of using VLOOKUP for inserting the data needed into the cells in sheet b
and using COUNTA to return '5' for the number of names present.

The main problem here is how do I automatically insert the 5 rows according to amount of names present.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: How to populate the column Buyer, Remaining and Total?  How about `=If(B3="","",B3")` (B3 is a cell in the reference table)?

Comment: But I would still need to add and remove the rows manually. I plan to protect the output sheet (sheet b) so that any changes I make in the reference sheet would automatically reflect into the output sheet. So it'll be fully automated depending on the amount of data from the reference sheet.

As I also have the "Total" at the bottom of the table, it is important that the rows increase and decrease automatically

Comment: what do you mean about include column header? Isn't "No.", "Seller", "Buyer", etc column header? Or am I missing something here? I also have never dabbled in vba before.

Comment: Pls update your screenshot to include row and column heading.

Comment: Edited to include the headers

Comment: If you want that merged cell (column A) you will need to do this in VBA. Otherwise you could use formulas. Do you have `FILTER` as formula? I am not sure about Excel 2021.

Comment: Just have a list based on something like unique() and if the downpayment is >0.

Comment: I don't have "FILTER" as formula, I use COUNTA to determine the amount of rows I need. and choosecols is not available on excel 2021 sadly. May I know how do I use VBA for this?

Answer (score 0):

Vlookup will return the first value matching the criteria. You need to use FILTER to return multiple values with the same condition:

`=LET(d,'Sheet1'!D3:D12,VSTACK(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS('Sheet1'!B3:D12,1,3),d),HSTACK("Total Down Payment",SUM(d))))`

Edit:
I noticed both `VSTACK/HSTACK` and `CHOOSECOLS` are not part of Excel 2021 (accessable using Excel for the web though).

Excel 2021 version would be:
`=LET(d,D3:D12,s,SEQUENCE(ROWS(d)),a,FILTER(INDEX(B3:D12,s,{1,3}),d),b,CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(,2),"Total Down Payment",SUM(d)),IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)+1)>ROWS(a),b,a))`

Answer (score 0):

`Seller` and `Down Payment` are populated with data from the reference table. Populating other columns are NOT mentaioned in OP. Please update as needed.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim ShtA As Worksheet ' reference table
    Dim ShtB As Worksheet ' output table
    Dim RowCnt as long
    set ShtA = Sheets("Sheet1")
    set ShtB = Sheets("Sheet2")
    RowCnt = ShtA.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row - 2
    If RowCnt > 0 Then
        With ShtB
            ' Change it to "B3:F10", if Total column should be cleaned
            .range("B3:E10").ClearContents
            .Range("B3").Resize(RowCnt,1).value = ShtA.Range("B2").Resize(RowCnt,1).value
            .Range("D3").Resize(RowCnt,1).value = ShtA.Range("C2").Resize(RowCnt,1).value
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```